# Accessing the index of an implicitly defined array in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I was trying to make a simple texture (fragment) shader that would loop through the uniform array  `atextures[]` which is implicitly defined. The following code returns the following error

Code:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D atextures[];
uniform int textureLength;

void main()
{
    for (int i=0; i<textureLength; i++){
        FragColor = texture(atextures[i], TexCoord);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Indirect index into implicitly-sized array
```

However when I  change the index from `i` to `0`, the following compiles fine. Did I setup the for loop wrong? Or did I initialise the array correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you have code that violates the specification. See the (most recent) [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 4.1.9. Arrays](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#basic-types):

> It is legal to declare an array without a size (unsized) and then later redeclare the same name as an array of the same type and specify a size, or **index it only with constant integral expressions** (implicitly sized).

---

What you try to do is not the create an implicitly-sized array, but an dynamically-sized array.

It is not possible to create uniform array with a variable size. A variable size is just possible for the bottommost variable in a [Shader Storage Block](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Shader_storage_blocks).
Anyway you should prefer to use an `sampler2DArray` instead of an array of `sampler2D`. With a sampler array, you must use a separate texture unit for each element, and the array index must be a [Dynamically uniform expression](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression)